# Playing audio from different class?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, static-methods

I have 15 or so activities. Each one of them has a method, and I want to play audio in that method. Now, I have the obvious option to copy and paste the following line of code into **each and every one of my activities** Now, if I wanted to change something, I would have to go back into **each and every one of my activities** again. Here is the code:

```
MediaPlayer pop = MediaPlayer.create(CurrentActivity.this, R.raw.pop);
        pop.start();
```

So, after searching the web for a few hours, I found that most people would just copy and paste it into each activity. So, I put the line of code (above) into a separate java class (which was a service by the way) tried to call that method in the service every time I needed to play the audio. So, I did the following:

```
public class TwentySeconds extends Service{
   public void myPop(View view){
    MediaPlayer pop = MediaPlayer.create(TwentySeconds.this, R.raw.pop);
    pop.start();
   }
}
```

Now, I got the error `non static method cannot be referenced from static context`. So, naturally, I tried to make method `myPop` `static`. Then, I got the error on `TwentySeconds.this` about being referenced from static context. So, it seems I am stuck. Changing the methods to static can't work, as I am trying to use an instance of the class as well using `this`. So, how should I go about calling method `myPop` where the `MediaPlayer` can successfully play?

Thanks for the advice,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if a utility method needs a `Context`, it is passed in.

```
public class Utilities {
    public static void myPop(Context context){
        MediaPlayer pop = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pop);
        pop.start();
    }
}
```

---

```
Utilities.myPop(CurrentActivity.this);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you just saved me another few hours! I have marked you as best answer, and liked your post!